# Does this selector a[href="yourlink"] work in IE 7 and 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

Does this selector `a[href="yourlink"]` work in IE 7 and 8? I'm using XHTML doctype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, is does.

See [this list](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) of CSS compatibility table ([attr] selector).